# Back to top button

Tags: position, sticky

How can i get my back to top button to stick to the side of the screen. So when i resize it, it will stay stuck to the left? Right now i have it in a container and it works well on smaller screens, but when i see it on a desktop it is in that container instead of all the way to the left of the screen.

```
#back-top {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: .7;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;

}



#back-top a {
    width: 108px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font: 11px/100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #bbb;
    /* background color transition */
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

#back-top a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
/* arrow icon (span tag) */
#back-top span {
    font-size: 8px !important;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    background:  url(../img/weed2.png) no-repeat center center;
    /* rounded corners */
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* background color transition */
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: `position: relative` and `position: fixed` in the same rule is pointless.

Comment: thanks that told me nothing.....